# Basic php to set column width in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template, joomla3.1

I am using Joomla with bootstrap to create a Joomla template. I have a 3 column layout (container totalling 12 so Bootstrap: span12). I am setting parameters in the Joomla backend to set the $left and $right column widths and then echoing those variables in my template to set the left and right div column widths (in index.php)

However, I want to use a simple bit of logic in my template to automatically calculate and set the span value of the middle column based on the $left and $right values entered in the parameters in the backend.

I literally know almost zero PHP so please forgive me for the crudeness of this code. I just want to check if what I am doing is correct or plain stupid or if there is a better way. Here's what I am doing...

```
<?php
$left = $this->params->get('sidebarLeftWidth', '');
$right = $this->params->get('sidebarRightWidth', '');

$grid = 12;
$span = $grid - ( $left + $right );
?>
```

and then to set the width of my middle column in my html - simply...

```
class="span<?php echo $span; ?>"
```

Comment: What is the '' in the params->get do (default value if not found). If it is then set it to 0 (zero). Otherwise use $span = $grid - ( intval($left) + intval($right) ); incase these values are not numeric or have addition characters i.e. 120px instead of 120.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jeff. I am setting the param input as a dropdown list so I know that the values of $left and $right will always be valid so I'm happy in that sense. Do you think it might be a security risk not to check that they are solely numeric? I admit I dont know the purpose of the  '' in the parameters. I am working out how to do this purely from reading the code from the default templates that come with Joomla and a few other examples. There is sweet all proper references for Joomla it seems its largely a case of trial and error and reverse engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that looks like it should work, if you have set the parameters correctly.

You don't actually say what's going wrong, i.e. what result is being generated so it's a bit hard to tell exactly, so here's some background info and suggestions that may help you figure it out. For template development you can find more at the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/) website on [Template Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Template_Development).

Assuming your code is in your templates `index.php`:

1. `$this->params->get('sidebarLeftWidth','')` is getting a template parameter called `sidebarLeftWidth`, but if that parameter isn't available then it's setting it to `''` effectively `null`.
2. The parameter names in your `get` should be defined with exactly the same spelling and capitalisation as in your `templateDetails.xml` file. If not your `$left` and `$right` may be empty. (*It will help if you edit your question to include the template XML, or part of it.*)
3. The `params` part is a [JRegistry object](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Registry/JRegistry.html) and returns a mixed type depending on what is originally stored in the name attribute of the object (usually this is a string, but it could be anything PHP can handle). To force an in value you may want to change your `get` lines to cast the results as integers and return 0 if nothing is found:

   `$left = (int) $this->params->get('sidebarLeftWidth', 0);`

   `$right = (int) $this->params->get('sidebarRightWidth', 0);`
4. Check the contents of your `params` in your debugger, i.e. check the values of each of your named parameters in the `$this->params` object. If you're not using an IDE try doing a `print_r()`:

   `echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->params, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate you taking the time to explain that for me - this site is awesome. It's not that my code will not run, it's just that while I am reasonably confident copying and pasting the usual stuff to create a Joomla template, I am still at the end of the day a web designer front end guy and I just basically take a guess at PHP.