# Joomla Variable Span grid

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I have got some problems with my template for joomla 3.1 with bootstrap.
I have no idea about php variables or something else. Question is how can I change the Content span12 to span 9 if I turn on some span3 module in right position?

[-------------content span12------------]
[-----content span9-------][module span3]

I found this: 
[Basic php to set column width in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582974/basic-php-to-set-column-width-in-joomla) but I don't get it. Can someone help me what I have to do? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem... if you "turn on" a module in right position, where is it being displayed, and does it give any layout issues ?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your template add this:

```
<?php
$main_width = 12;
if ($this->countModules('right'))
  $main_width = 9;
?>
```

then where you output content modify:

```
<div class="main-content span<?php echo $main_width; ?>">--Content--</div>
<?php if ($this->countModules('right') : ?>
  <div class="right-module span3">--Right modules output--</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I found something what works:

if($this->countModules('left and right') == 0) $contentwidth = "12"; 
if($this->countModules('left or right') == 1) $contentwidth = "8"; 

<div class="span<?php echo $contentwidth; ?>">
<article class="article"><jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" /></article>
</div>

Comment: Well it's completely the same as my code, just adding left position too. :)